# Turn on PC power remotely through the Internet?

Tags: power, remote, remote-access, wake-on-lan

I use SVN for my work at home and office, but I usually forget to commit the changes before shutdown. Therefore, I wish I could turn on my home/office PC at office/home. I already have TeamViewer installed on both PCs, so it will be okay as soon as the power is turned on.

I have read many articles about this, I found both my PC and office computers support `Wake-on-LAN`. However, I don't know much about other config. And I need to turn on my computers through the Internet, not on LAN.

My office Internet connection has static IP, however, my home Internet connection has dynamic IP, it changes as soon as I reset the modem, but it is not a big problem, I rarely turn the Internet modem off. And I don't have privilege to config office Internet connection, but I have Administration privilege on both PCs.

Please give me details steps to turn on my office PC from home, and turn on my home PC from office.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WOL - Wake On Lan over internet](http://superuser.com/questions/266009/wol-wake-on-lan-over-internet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the free version of [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/UK/). This supports WOL out of the box. On most PCs it just works – on others it's a bit of playing around in BIOS settings.