# WOL over Internet success for a while but fail after a period of time

Tags: lan, wake-on-lan, arp

I have a computer in my home LAN, and i have successfully set up my computer and router to use wol over Internet.

The problem is, after a period of time(say, a night), the next day i want to start my computer over Internet it failed, but it can be waken up from home LAN.

I have the correct public IP of my router. I use [this link](http://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/woli.aspx) for WOL over Internet

The answer for [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/266009/wol-wake-on-lan-over-internet) seems good, but i don't think it explains why WOL over Internet fail but WOL success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually right: the question is not fully answered [by Majenko](https://superuser.com/questions/266009/wol-wake-on-lan-over-internet).

The reason is that the WOL packets sent over the Internet (WOI?) are packets of a special nature, called *subnet directed broadcasts* (*SDB*s). They owe their name to the fact that, once they reach the final router, they are not forwarded using an IP address to a specific pc, but are instead converted into *broadcast* packets, sent to *all* pcs on the LAN. This is precisely the technique used by *depicus* in the Web page you refer to, as explained by depicus himself in the [Wake on Lan over the Internet](http://www.depicus.com/wake-on-lan/what-is-wake-on-lan.aspx) section.

Thus Majenko's explanation (that the router will first try to identify the pc to send the magic packet to, and it will cease to do so once its ARP cache has expired because the sleeping pc cannot reply to ARP requests) is wrong. The subnet directed broadcast is transformed into an ARP broadcast, without any need for IP-routing.

So why does this mechanism cease working? I do not know for sure. I can speculate, however, that this is a security feature of your router. *SDB*s are perfect vehicles for an infamous DDoS attack, called the *smurf* attack. In the same section referenced above, *depicus* states that Cisco routers have an option forbidding *SDB*s. It is possible your router has a security feature according to which it will explode *SDB*s if and only if it can locate the MAC address to which they are addressed. This will make it impossible, for an outside attacker, to take advantage of this vulnerability: how can an outsider *guess* a MAC address actually present on a given LAN?

There is one simple way to check this explanation: try some of the solutions for WOL over the Internet (WOI?) proposed in DD-WRT's [WOL page](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/WOL). Not all of them are open to you, if you do not have a DD-WRT router, but some **are**. And, should you decide to get a DD-WRT router (some of Buffalos' are, natively), read the [scripts to wake-up a specific pc](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Useful_Scripts#Web_Server_Wake-up), which are quite nice and convenient.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however i don't think the root cause is "a security feature of your router" you speculated, because i said I have  set up WOL over Internet successfully, if this is a security feature of my router, how does this work?

Comment: @July: like I said in the answer. If the router sees that the MAC address to which the magic packet is addressed exists on the LAN (= if it is in the ARP cache), then it forwards it. Otherwise, if it is not in the cache, the router assumes this is a smurf attack, and does not explode the magic packet.

Comment: OK i see, so if i can add a static entry to the router ARP table, that may fix the problem, right?

Comment: @July Absolutely yes.

Comment: Thanks, one more question, the static ARP binding feature of the router may do the job, with it i can add MAC->IP binding entries, right?

Comment: @July Not sure, depends on router. With my routers, I have 'Address Reservation', a bit like having a static IP. The router is told to associate always the same IP address to the given (I have to put it in by hand) MAC address. At this point, the router knows both MAC address and IP address of this ethernet interface. I suggest you search for the same feature. You may also try port-forwarding, see the DD-WRT web page.