# Enable WOL from internet

Tags: networking, router, switch, wake-on-lan

I'm trying to enable WOL over the internet. I have created Discord Bot that sends a magic packet using python library https://pypi.org/project/wakeonlan/ whenever I send a special command to discord.

While I host the bot on my desktop computer within my local area network and send a special command to Discord that bot will send a magic packet to my public ip (using hostname). I'm using ddns no-ip to resolve my ip. My modem router only support no-ip out of the box. This works just fine and my second pc boots up *(later when I say "second pc" I always mean a pc that I'm tryign to wake up)*.

Now if I stop hosting my discord bot on my desktop pc and host it in Azure it doesn't always work. Sometimes it does and to my understanding it's due to the fact that my router is caching ARP entries for some time. But funnily enough even if it works briefly it never works if I have any other computer connected to my router via network cable other than the pc I'm trying to boot up. And after some time it stops working completely anyway.

So I have a modem from my ISP which has a build in router (and switch I guess because it has four ports). Unfortunately I can't find a model of it. Like I said it supports ddns (no-ip). It supports ip reservations so I can assign predefined IP addresses to certain mac addresses. This way I have defined that PC I'm trying to wake up always get's a same IP address. Then I have created port forwarding rule in that router saying that any incoming UDP packet (magic packet my bot is sending) coming to port 7 (I have also tried port 9) is forwarded to that IP address that I have attached to my second pc MAC address.

At this point I also want to say that apparently my router doesn't support forwarding to broadcast IP addresses.

I did some research and it occurred to me that what I have done might not be enough. People say that I should be able to manually add entries to ARP map table which unfortunately my current router / switch can't do.

So, I went and bought a second hand TP-LINK TL-SG2008 smart switch that supports static ARP maps and other interesting stuff which I don't know about but might be handy.

Now instead of connecting my second pc directly to my modem/router I connect my new switch to my modem/router instead. TL-SG2008 switch gets an IP address from DHCP (which I have configured again to be always same) and I'm able to login to admin portal using its IP address and web browser.

There I have defined static ARP map entry saying that my second pc MAC address maps to this particular IP. Remember that it's the IP that I already defined in my router ip reservation list so that no other device will ever get it.

Now finally I connected my second pc to my new switch, hosted discord bot in Azure, sent a command to discord and absolutely nothing.

Then I hosted bot locally, sent a command to Discord and it works.

Then I connected another pc to my modem/router, hosted bot locally, sent command to Discord and it's not working. However this is tiniest of the problems for now and I'm able to ignore it for now but I just wanted to point it out because it might give some ideas what's happening.

At this point I'm lost and clueless how this should work and with given devices am I even able to achieve this at all?

It bothers me greatly that it works from the internet some time so clearly it is possible in theory at least.

Any help would be appreciated and I'm happy to share more information as needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WOL - Wake On Lan over internet](https://superuser.com/questions/266009/wol-wake-on-lan-over-internet)

Comment: Not really. My situation differs from that, if I understood correctly, the way that I have two switches and first switch doesn't support static APR mapping while second one does. I wish I could get rid of the first switch but it's baked into my modem router so I would have to buy modem and router separately and then use only the switch that supports static ARPs. Again, if I understood correctly.

Comment: The integrated switch is not the problem. The kind of ARP table that's being used here is a router/host thing – switches are transparent to ARP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send the packet to an IP address that's on an Ethernet network, the router **must** know the corresponding Ethernet address (the MAC address) to direct the packet to. If the system is asleep for so long that the router's ARP-cache entry expires, and if there's no response to a new ARP query, then the router will not forward the packet anywhere. (Forwarding to the 'broadcast' MAC as a last resort is, I believe, explicitly forbidden in the IPv4 specification.)

So you most likely *will* need to forward the packets to some other device (host or router, but *not* a switch) which can do that. You could use either your other desktop, or something like a 1W "raspberry pi" type of computer – as long as it's connected to the same subnet, it is supposed to work.

The wake packet doesn't necessarily have to be sent directly to your MAC, it can also be broadcast to the entire network, as long as it reaches the computer's Ethernet interface *somehow* (the "MAC to be woken up" is embedded within the packet's payload), but most routers indeed won't support specifying a broadcast IP address; they're all based on the same Linux iptables, which doesn't support that. I have not tested whether multicast addresses (like the "all nodes" 224.0.0.1) would work but I suspect they won't.

(The specific UDP port is also irrelevant. Port 9 is officially assigned as the "discard" port so it would be most suitable in principle, but the Ethernet card literally doesn't care.)

You could experiment with the *wake on pattern* feature of WoL (which is available e.g. if you disable "Only allow management stations to wake this computer" on Windows), as it might allow *the ARP request itself* to wake the computer, but this will likely result in the system waking up much too often. (I've also heard of some NICs having "ARP offload", where the NIC itself would reply to ARP requests even while the system was asleep, but I don't remember ever seeing that in practice.)

> I did some research and it occurred to me that what I have done might not be enough. People say that I should be able to manually add entries to ARP map table which unfortunately my current router / switch can't do.

The ARP table in question belongs to the "router" part of the device. While all routers (and hosts) have an ARP table, it's quite rare for a typical home "wireless router" to support adding static entries.

> So, I went and bought a second hand TP-LINK TL-SG2008 smart switch that supports static ARP maps and other interesting stuff which I don't know about but might be handy.

A switch won't help at all. If the router doesn't know the right MAC address, it isn't going to ask the switch about it; it just won't be able to send the packet at all.

ARP mapping in switches has a different purpose – it's a filter that is meant to prevent host A from falsely claiming the IP address of host B (i.e. it doesn't populate the ARP cache, quite the opposite: it *blocks* the unwanted ARP responses).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This clears things up. After I wrote this question I kept looking for solution and understood myself too that buying a switch was waste of money. But I then took my wallet out again and bought TP-LINK AX1500 router that supports IP to MAC bindings. I also learned that I was able to set my device from ISP for bridged mode and that way take advantage of my new router. I set IP to MAC in my new router and WOL over the internet now seems to work. I'm little skeptical as it has been up and running only a day or so, but so far everything is good.

Comment: Make sure it's the right kind of "IP to MAC bindings"; in most routers it means static DHCP leases and has no effect on ARP. (Personally I lean towards Mikrotik hardware for cheap advanced routing; they might not have the best Wi-Fi support, but nothing requires both things to be done on the same device, e.g. the AX1500 in bridge/AP mode could serve WiFi while being connected to something else that routes IP.)

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure it is as I have also added that same MAC to ip reservation list. It's quite interesting actually. When a packet comes in and there's no machine with that IP the router still knows where to send that magic packet because I have added ARP entry manually. And then when the magic packet makes computer to boot it receives that IP from DHCP where I have defined that this particular MAC should always receive this particular IP